# Squid modify HTTP-Request and set cookie

Tags: http, squid, httpcookie

I would like to use Squid Proxy to manipulate HTTP-Request to specific websites.

A cookie which should be inserted into every request to http://example.com

Now everybody using the proxy and surfing to http://example.com is automatically logged in via the cookie.

I read about Content Adaption on this site:
http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation

I would like to use something like http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_add/ .

Can anybody help me?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Content adaptation is the best option. Other options aren't flexible to modify the Set-Cookie header. You should change that header keeping the information that it already has, so it's the best option.

I wrote an ICAP server in Python some time ago, you can use it as base for your work, it's hosted on [Github](https://github.com/diegows/misc/blob/master/adv-indonesia/usr/local/bin/icap-server.py)